# Refactor large routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making various routes with a format like below:

```
  get "address/1000broadway"
  get "address/300main"
```

This list of routes will likely grow into the thousands.  What is the best way to manage this?  Can I simply list them all out in the routes file?  Or is better to require various files that include the routes?  Are there any potential performance issues with the application having to load a large routes.rb file?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why `1000broadway` and `300main` aren't simply handled as variables?

Comment: The attribute is :location.  Each address will have a unique template named by its location attribute; app/views/address/1000broadway.html.erb, app/views/address/300main.html.erb  So in addition there will be thousands of templates too which also might be an issue.

Comment: The issue is each address has a unique set of specifications that cannot be all put into database fields.  Rather I have decided to write out the information in html and put it into the template manually.  I know it is probably way beyond rails convention.

Comment: Man, that sounds like a painful path to follow. If each one is truly unique, this might be the best approach, but is there really no way that you can find, say, eight or twenty of these that are "common" in some way and reduce the amount of static content / templating you've got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the comments,
this feels very much like a CMS type problem.

For that I'd say "treat each address as a 'page', and chuck the custom layout in the database"

But you reckon the templating is too complex to deal with this way.

Have you looked at [liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid)?
Namely, it'd allow you to store the template in the database, but use conditional logic.

As a bare minimum,
I'd suggest organising your urls.

```
resources :address do
  collection do
    get :1000broadway
    get :300main
  end
end
```

Comment: I've decided to put all of the text into the database and use RedCloth for formatting.